# How to force a binding update when adding a Element to a Array using sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel

Tags: javascript, sapui5, hana

I have defined a `sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel` like this:

```
var viewModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
    items: [
        { name: 'item 1'},
        { name: 'item 2'},
        { name: 'item 3'}
    ]
});
this.getView().setModel(viewModel, 'viewModel');
```

Now I want to add a new Element to the `items` Array and force a update to all Bindings. What's the best way/ best practice to do that? By now I'm doing it like this:

```
var model = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({ name: null });

var form = new sap.ui.layout.form.SimpleForm({
    // ... some code here with binding to `model` ...
});

form.setModel(model);

// ... some code here to trigger the code below ...

var viewModel = this.getModel('viewModel');
var items = viewModel.getProperty('/items');
items.push(model.getData());
viewModel.setProperty('/items', items);
```

But it looks kind of wrong. Is there a better way to update the viewModel?

Comment: What is wrong with using `viewModel.setProperty(sPath, aUpdatedArray)`? I use it all the time, and it updates the bindings perfectly. And by not refreshing the whole model, you don't have the side-effect of a slight flickering in your UI when **all** controls are updated

Comment: Nothing is wrong with it, it's *just* not that nice. Thought there may be a better coding style. But it seems there isn't something in UI5. So I wrote this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/33815354/1692735

Comment: Ah I see :) Yeah, you could end up with quite some '*get property as array -- add obj to array / remove obj from array -- set property with updated array*' combo's. For adding I could see it may be nicer, but for deleting, it may not be that simple (handling delete by index, id, object, duplicates, ranges, etc)

Answer (score 0):

The way you use is one of the two I also use, the other one is to change the data directly in the model and call [refresh](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.Model.html#refresh) to update the bindings

```
var model = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel([]);
model.getData().push({aKey: "aValue"});
model.refresh();
```

Adding an item in your example would be

```
var model = this.getView();
model.getData().items.push({name: "someName"});
model.refresh();
```

Comment: Ok, but this will refresh *all* bindings within the model? Not only the `/items` binding? (if there are more, like `/totalPrice` or `/users` or so on...)? Isn't there something like `model.refresh('/items');`?

Comment: As I know there is no such method. But refreshing the bindings is nothing bad, as it only tells yout controls that the value might have changed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I found a bit nicer solution. First I extended the JSONModel like this:

```
sap.ui.define([
    'sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel'
], function(JSONModel) {
    'use strict';

    return JSONModel.extend('app.model.JSONModelWithListProperty', {

        appendToList: function(property, itemToAppend) {
            var arr = this.getProperty(property);
            if ($.isArray(arr)) {
                arr.push(itemToAppend);
            }
            this.setProperty(property, arr);
            return this;
        }
    });
});
```

Instantiation now looks like this:

```
var viewModel = new app.model.JSONModelWithListProperty({
    items: [
        { name: 'item 1'},
        { name: 'item 2'},
        { name: 'item 3'}
    ]
});
this.getView().setModel(viewModel, 'viewModel');
```

So I can finally update the list by simply calling:

```
this.getModel('viewModel').appendToList('/items', model.getData());
```

Looks a bit nicer to me and saves me some lines of code. I'm open to any suggestions.